# UWP is there any way to set Horisontal Align = Center for Icon in the AppBarButton?

Tags: xaml, button, uwp, commandbar

I have:

```
<CommandBar ..>
..
<CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
<AppBarButton Name="btnStop" ToolTipService.ToolTip="btnStop">
                    <FontIcon FontFamily="{StaticResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}" Glyph="&#xE73B;" Foreground="Red"/>
                </AppBarButton>
</CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
</CommandBar>
```

it looks the same way: 
[image]

Is there any way to align Icon in Center?
If I set In "Live Explorer Property"
Local -> Icon -> Handout Visual -> Offset = <5,0,0>
It looks better. How to do the same in code?

Comment: Your markup works for me - it is horizontally aligned.  Perhaps you have a global style interfering with appbarbutton that is shifting things to the left for you?

Comment: @Mark W, thank you a lot for the answer. I will try to find the problem in my own code.

Answer (score 0):

if you do not have label, should be LabelPosition="Collapsed"